# How to filter common values of two columns with advanced filter?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one column containing some common values that are in another column. I want to filter values from one column that are present in other column but without using VLOOKUP. How can i do it using advanced filter??

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: If you can include the reason for excluding vlookup, it might help drive better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to filter so only the values in column **A** that are also in column **B** are visible.  We use a "helper" column.  In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$20,A2)>0,1,0)
```

and copy down.  Then set the filter for only **1** in column **C**:

[image]